# how to use mysql database in docker-compse

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I want to use docker-compose fast build a service and a database,but it didn't work

this is the spring-boot-data-jpa configuration

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: root
    password: root
    url: jdbc:mysql://${ip}:3306/db?&useUnicode=yes&serverTimezone=CTT&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=true
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database: mysql
```

this is Dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAVA_OPTS
ENV JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS
ADD target/spring-boot-db-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar spring-boot-db-service.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar spring-boot-db-service.jar
```

this is the docker-compose file

docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services: 
  dbservice: 
    image: dbservice:latest
    hostname: dbservice
    environment: 
      - ip=mysql
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    networks:
      - db
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.31
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
    networks: 
      - db
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    hostname: mysql
networks: 
  db:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what actually happens?  Can you edit the question to include the actual error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app from docker compose you need to change the host from ip to the compose service name, in this case `mysql`

your connection string will be

`url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/db?&useUnicode=yes&serverTimezone=CTT&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=tru`

more details you can find on the docs https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: I use `${ip}` to get ip  from environment that configured in docker-compose file.